# Suppose A is a 100x100 real symmetric matrix whose diagonal entries are all positive. Then which of the following is necessarily true?

Tags: matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $100\times 100$ real symmetric matrix whose diagonal entries are all positive. Then which of the following is necessarily true?

(A) All eigenvalues of $A$ are greater than $0$
(B) no eigenvalue of $A$ is greater than $0$
(C) at least one eigenvalue of $A$ is greater than $0$
(D) none of these.

Comment: Logic nitpick: If it turns out that A, B, C all have counterexamples, is the answer really D? Since A clearly is true for _some_ matrices (like the identity matrix), "none of these" isn't _necessarily_ true, is it? Also, if A is necessarily true, then C is also necessarily true, which is evidence of poor problem authorship.

Comment: @Arthur The first three are logical statements. In none of them is true, then $D$ is intended. On strict reading $D$ should read "none of the above statements is true" - at the moment, strictly speaking, it excludes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, (C) is the answer, as sum of eigenvalues = sum of diagonal entries > 0. Therefore, at least one eigenvalue of $A$ is positive.